# MacBook Pro still boots slowly after installing SSD

Tags: macos, mac, boot, ssd, hardware-failure

I've recently exchanged the old HDD from my MacBook Pro with a Samsung 840 Pro 512GB SSD, but the boot time didn't actually get faster.

I've already selected the SSD as my boot volume, I've already used disk utility to verify the volume and the permissions. I even reset PRAM a couple of times, and enabled trim, but nothing works.

The thing is, most people (I already researched this quite a lot) with similar problems seem to be stuck before the Apple logo appears. As for me, the Apple logo appears after about 5 seconds, but then it takes another 50 seconds to get to the login screen. Shutdown also seems a bit slow.

For further info: It's a MacBook Pro early 2011 running OS X 10.9.2. The system is quite new (not a lot of data or anything).

Edit: New information:
I've had the inkling suspicion that it might not be the SSDs fault but rather an underlying problem that only became apparent when I expected faster boot times.
So today I excanged my SSD with my colleague's SSD (same model, same size) and it would still take almost a minute to boot. So its neither the SSD's nor the system's fault. When I exchanged my ram with my colleague's ram (same  amount but different manufacturer) the boot time also stayed the same.
For reference: My colleague's MacBook Pro boots in 12 seconds.

So I think I can rule out the OS, the SSD and the ram.
When I looked through the bootlog, the only thing standing out is this section:

> Mar 11 08:41:03 lilas-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Ethernet [AppleBCM5701Ethernet]: Link up on >en0,
>  1-Gigabit, Full-duplex, Symmetric flow-control, EEE enabled, Debug 
> [796d,0301,0de1,0300,cde1,3c00]
>   Mar 11 08:41:06 lilas-MacBook-Pro.local configd[19]: network changed: v4(en0+:10.7.7.158) >DNS+
>  Proxy+ SMB
>   Mar 11 08:41:10 lilas-MacBook-Pro.local ntpd[44]: proto: precision = 1.000 usec
>   Mar 11 08:41:12 lilas-MacBook-Pro.local apsd[82]: Unrecognized leaf certificate
>   Mar 11 08:41:16 lilas-MacBook-Pro.local stackshot[50]: Timed out waiting for IOKit to finish matching.
>   Mar 11 08:41:17 lilas-MacBook-Pro.local apsd[82]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
>   Mar 11 08:41:22 lilas-MacBook-Pro.local awacsd[80]: Exiting
>   Mar 11 08:41:40 lilas-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: en3: promiscuous mode enable succeeded

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some trouble with your network card.

Try to disable the "Back to my Mac". Also, the last line ([promiscuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode)) says that you've enabled an estate to your wifi card, a monitor state. Maybe disabling it helps.